# Replace all spaces before the 4th comma with commas in NOTEPAD++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

In a text file, I need to replace all the spaces before the 4th comma with commas. Everything after the 4th comma must remain intact.

**Example**

A B C,D,E F,G H,I J, word, word... etc

Must become:

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I J, word, word... etc

How can I do that?

I haven't tried anything except doing it manually line by line, because I don't know how to do it in a way that will be successful.

Comment: Please add samples to your question. Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer. One thing that is not clear: do you expect spaces in places such as before a comma, as in `,AB ,C` and if so, should it become `,AB,,C`?

Comment: I think you want to replace all spaces before the first comma.

Comment: No, there wont be any spaces before a comma. Also it must be replaced with only one comma to keep the format of the file intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could perform a 3-step replace

1. use this pattern
   `(^(([^,]*,){4}[^ ]*)|\G[^ ]*)\K` - note the pattern ends with a white space - to replace all spaces after the 4th comma with a known character or sets of characters ie `~~`.
   your output will look like this:
   `A B C,D,E F,G H,I~~J,~~word,~~word...~~etc`
2. replace all spaces with commas
3. replace `~~` with space

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tP5mO6)